# Covariance between centered and scaled normal entries of a random vector

Tags: probability-distributions, covariance

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1384414/152225) and following a tip by @Ian in the comments.

If $X_1,\dots,X_n  \sim \text{ i.i.d. } N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\displaystyle \bar X= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n},$ the covariance of the random variables $Y_i=\frac{X_i-\bar X}{\sigma}$ (which I supposed can be read as centered and scaled entries of a random vector) is $-1/n.$

I see that

$$\begin{align}
\small
\operatorname{cov}\left(Y_i,Y_j\right) = {} & \small \operatorname{cov} \left(\frac{(X_i-\bar X)}{\sigma},\frac{(X_j-\bar X)}{\sigma}\right)\\[2ex]
= {} &\small\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\big[(X_i-\bar X)(X_j-\bar X)\big] - E\big[X_i-\bar X\big]E\big[X_j-\bar X\big]\\[2ex]
= {} & \small \frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\big[(X_i-\bar X)(X_j-\bar X)\big]\\[2ex]
= {} & \small \frac{1}{\sigma^2}E[(X_i-\mu+\mu-\overline{X})(X_j-\mu+\mu-\overline{X})]\\[2ex]
= {} &\small \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left( E[(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)]+E[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]+E[(X_j-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]+E[(\mu-\overline{X})^2]\right)\\[2ex]
= {} &\small\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left( E[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]+E[(X_j-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]+E[(\mu-\overline{X})^2]\right)
\end{align}$$

The last term $E[(\mu-\overline{X})^2=\operatorname{var}(\bar X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ as derived [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/167).

Does, then

$$E[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]+E[(X_j-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})] \overset{?}= \frac{-2\sigma^2}{n} \text{ ?}$$

Comment: Why are you adjusting your sample by the sample mean, but with the population variance?  Should you not be adjusting by both the sample mean and sample variance ... or by population mean and population variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\c}{\operatorname{cov}}$You seem to be doing it the hard way.

\begin{align}
& \c(X_i - \overline X, X_j - \overline X) \\[10pt]
= {} & \c(X_i,X_j) - \c(X_i,\overline X) - \c(\overline X, X_j) + \c(\overline X,\overline X) \\[10pt]
= {} & 0 - \c\left( X_i, \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) - \c\left( \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n, X_j \right) + \operatorname{var}(\overline X) \\[10pt]
= {} & - \frac{\sigma^2} n - \frac{\sigma^2} n + \frac{\sigma^2} n = \frac{-\sigma^2} n.
\end{align}

Comment: Note to self: $cov \left( X_i, \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right)=\frac{1}{n} cov \left( X_i, X_1+\cdots+X_n\right)=\frac{1}{n} [cov (X_i, X_1)+\cdots+cov(X_i,X_i)+\cdots+cov(X_i,X_n)]=\frac{1}{n}[0+\cdots+\sigma^2+\cdots+0]$